# Is there a Christian denomination that only considers the Son and the Father to be persons of God?

Tags: nature-of-god, denomination-survey, persons-of-the-trinity, binitarian

Is there a Christian denomination that holds only the Son and the Father as persons of God? (Only two persons) -- as opposed to Trinitarianism and Unitarianism. Has it been upheld by anyone in Christian history?